# sprintf messing around with my pointers and data?

Tags: c

```
char purl[1024];
unsigned char * puMember;
unsigned char uMember;
puMember = &uMember;

unsigned char * pMember;
unsigned char Member;
pMember = &Member;

printf("member: %s\n",pMember);
printf("username :%s\n",puMember);
sprintf(purl, "Username: %s %s",puMember,pMember);
printf("URL:%s\n",purl);
printf("member: %s\n",puMember);
printf("username :%s\n",pMember);
```

Output

```
member: 12345678
username :User1
URL: username: cUser1 ser1
member: User1
username :ser1
```

Im confused into why sprintf is messing up my pointers once its been executed.

pMember has 12345678 and puMember has User1, im trying to format the them into a string (purl) but it seems that sprintf is messing them up :/

Any help how i could accomplish this?

Comment: What do the definitions of these variables look like? I'm suspecting that you're overflowing `purl`.

Comment: we want the definitions of `pMember`, `puMember`, `purl`; and if it is not too much trouble `pUserID` and `pMemberID`. Thanks

Comment: added a bit more info, hopefully this helps

Comment: A stylistic comment - don't use temporaries for pointers to variables, it's hard to follow. Use `&var` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very strange - if `pMember` and `puMember` point to single chars, why `printf` them as a mull-terminated string? It will print anything until it finds a null in memory.

Likewise, `sprintf` will keep reading memory after the `Member` and `uMember` chars and fill up `purl` - depending on when it finds a null byte in memory.

Using `snprintf` instead of `printf` will avoid the buffer overrun, but what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Well i printf them because i've filled both of them with a value and the last char[] is '\0' so it printf's without any issues. Im trying to get purl as a string to equal "Username: 123456789, User1" by passing the 2 variables to create that type of string as it changes everything.

Comment: `Member` and `uMember` only contain 1 char. How can you "fill them", plus ad a terminating null? What you're really doing is overwriting adjacent memory.

Comment: I see what you mean! I've been ++ing the pointer and adding char's and not realising that its not memory allocated to me but writing elsewhere. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting a buffer somewhere. Replace the `sprintf` with [`snprintf`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) to let the C library know exactly how much space you have in the target buffer, e.g:

```
char buffer[32];
snprintf( buffer, 32, "my text: %s\n", some_char_ptr );
```

#### Edit 0:

Strings in C are zero-terminated, meaning there's one extra byte at the end of the memory chunk that has value `'\0'`, and that signals end of the string. That what C library assumes for string functions like `strlen` and `strcpy`, and for `%s` format specifier for all `printf`s. Otherwise these library functions would run through the memory till either zero-value byte is found or OS kills your program for access to unmapped memory.

Comment: +1 - `sprintf` in production code is a bug, always use `snprintf`

Comment: `snprintf` has its uses. I don't see how it helps here ;) -- As it forces you to use a C99 compiler it may even be counterproductive.

Comment: @pmg - it avoids one problem, specifically the buffer overrun.

Comment: Before worrying about buffer overruns, the OP should worry about not treating random `char`s in memory as "string"s :) -- and there was no buffer overrun in the original code: the `purl` array has space for 1024 characters.

Comment: @pmg, last time I checked it was 2011 - it might be time to start using that 1999 standard already ... :)

Comment: @Nikolai: agree. just not VLAs ( or mixed declarations and code :P )

Comment: I'd say that snprintf in production code is also a bug, unless you are dealing with a lot of float-to-string formatting. Not only does s*printf take up huge amounts of memory, it is also very slow. If you are only doing int-to-string / string-to-int, write your own routines for it. 30 minutes of work and then you reuse them in all your programming projects in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
char purl[1024];
unsigned char * puMember;
unsigned char uMember;
```

`uMember` has space for 1 character; `'F'` or `'4'` or `'\0'`

```
puMember = &uMember;
```

`puMember` points to that character. And that character alone: the object is 1 byte in size.

```
unsigned char * pMember;
unsigned char Member;
```

`Member` has space for 1 character

```
pMember = &Member;
```

`pMember` points to 1 character.

```
printf("member: %s\n",pMember);
```

No, no, no. pMember does not point to a "string". You've invoked Undefined Behaviour: anything can happen

```
printf("username :%s\n",puMember);
```

No, no, no. puMember does not point to a "string". You've invoked Undefined Behaviour: anything can happen

```
sprintf(purl, "Username: %s %s",puMember,pMember);
```

No, no, no. puMember and pMember do not point to "string"s. You've invoked Undefined Behaviour: anything can happen

```
printf("URL:%s\n",purl);
printf("member: %s\n",puMember);
printf("username :%s\n",pMember);
```

No, no, no ...

Comment: Is it undefined behavior, or unpredictable behavior? `printf` and `sprintf` should keep reading chars until they reach a null.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. *Suppose the character lies at a boundary of "something" and crossing that boundary starts self-destruction. doing `printf("%s\n", pMember);` could be the same as `selfdestruct(SELFDESTRUCT_IMMED);` :)*